Center the dimension labels in my pivot table report
I'm working on a Looker Studio report and I'd like to center the dimension labels in my pivot table. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a dedicated option for this. I've tried adjusting column widths and text formatting (like left/right align) but haven't achieved a perfectly centered look.
Is there a way to truly center dimension labels within Looker Studio pivot tables?
If not, are there any known workarounds or alternative chart types that might offer better centering options?
Image
